# Debugging 32 bit MS DOS program

Tags: debugging, msdos

I have 32 bit MS DOS programs (used DOS extender DOS4GW.EXE). Program compiled with WATCOM C++ 32 bit, I am looking for debugger and disassembler for Win7, Win10 or WinME. Who knows?

Comment: You might be better off running an emulated environment under MAME or similar.

Comment: I can even disassemble under WinME, for example I ran IDA under WinME - there is only a 16-bit option for the DOS program. There is no 32 bit. Old DOS game, old WinME - but how to disassemble a 32-bit program is unknown.

Comment: Windows IDA Freeware 5 can diassemble 16bit and 32bit DOS Exes - but maybe this old version can't understand your linear watcom exe image - but newer IDA freewares disables the DOS exe support - the paid variant can disassemble Watcom LE exes

Comment: I using IDA Freeware 5, but under Win7 this IDA has options disassemble 16 bit and 32 bit exes and it recognize my 32 bit WATCOM exe file. But same IDA under WinME has only 16 bit option- there is no 32 bit.

Comment: MAME has a built-in debugger that can disassemble the 32-bit code, which is why I was suggesting it.